# Using differentiation to find the gradient at the normal

Tags: calculus, geometry, graphing-functions

I have a point $Q$ that lies on the curve $C$, where $C=\frac{3x^2}{4}-4x-10$. The point $Q$ is such that the gradient of the normal to $C$ at $Q$ is $-2$, how can I find the $x$-coord of $Q$?

So far I have tried differentiation however I am not very good at it since the fraction coefficient confuses me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first we will look at how to differentiate $C$. Don't worry about the fractional coefficient we can take that out if you'd like. So:

$$\frac{3x^2}{4}=\frac{3}{4}(x^2) \text{ then differentiating} \rightarrow  \frac{3}{4}(2x)=\frac{3x}{2}$$

So if we  differentiate $C$ we get $C'=\frac{3x}{2}-4$. Which is the gradient at any point $x$. Also what we should know is the tangent is the gradient at that point. But the *normal* is perpendicular to it! Which means in terms of the tangent it is the *negative reciprocal* ! So if our tangent's gradient was $2$, then the normals gradient would be $\frac{-1}{2}$.

So generally:

$$\text{Gradient of Tangent}=\frac{-1}{\text{Gradient of Normal}}$$

So we have the gradient of the normal which is $-2$, so finding the gradient of the tangent we get $\frac{1}{2}$ from the method above! So then we can set our new gradient equal to our $C'$ formula!
$$C'=\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3x}{2}-4$$

I'm sure you can do the last step! Just re-arrange for x! Hope this helps!

Comment: Lucky I had just written up a very similar question :)